# Как расширить интерфейс у компонента Autocomplete MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Подскажите пожалуйста, как расширить интерфейс у компонента Autocomplete MUI v5?

TS ругается, а как поправить не знаю((

> Generic type 'AutocompleteProps<T, Multiple, DisableClearable,
> FreeSolo, ChipComponent>' requires between 4 and 5 type arguments.

```
import {
  Autocomplete as MuiAutocomplete,
  AutocompleteProps,
  TextField
} from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

interface IStyledAutocompleteProps extends AutocompleteProps {
  options: any;
}

const Autocomplete = styled(
  MuiAutocomplete,
  {}
)<IStyledAutocompleteProps>(({ theme }) => ({})) as typeof MuiAutocomplete;

const StyledAutocomplete: React.FC<IStyledAutocompleteProps> = ({
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...props}
      options={props.options}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField variant="outlined" {...params} />}
    />
  );
};

export default StyledAutocomplete;
```

Codesandbox с кодом: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-haslett-lybwuh?file=/src/App.tsx

**UPD**
Если сделать так, то будет другая ошибка с которой тоже непонятно что делать

```
interface IStyledAutocompleteProps<T> extends AutocompleteProps<T, Multiple, DisableClearable, FreeSolo, ChipComponent> {
  options: any;
}
```

Ошибка

> Generic type 'IStyledAutocompleteProps' requires 1 type argument

Comment: `requires between 4 and 5 type arguments.` - не хватает аргументов, вероятно атрибуты

Comment: @DaniilLoban а как их указать? для меня это сложная типизация..не понимаю какой синтаксис и куда/что писать

Comment: вот сюда `extends AutocompleteProps<any, any, any, any, any>`, но конечно не `any`, а то что требуется, речь шла про аргументы типа `type arguments`

Comment: @DaniilLoban тоже другая ошибка появляется...какой-то аргумент просит указать, а я не знаю что именно нужно и какой синтаксис. Добавил UPD с кодом

Comment: я бы опробовал решение @MrYogurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно, не понял зачем вы пишете то, что пишете, но вот так не получаю никаких ошибок:

```
import { Autocomplete as MuiAutocomplete, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

interface IStyledAutocompleteProps {
  options: {
    label: string;
    year: number;
  }[];
}

const Autocomplete = styled(MuiAutocomplete)(({ theme }) => ({}));

const StyledAutocomplete: React.FC<IStyledAutocompleteProps> = ({
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...props}
      options={props.options}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField variant="outlined" {...params} />}
    />
  );
};

export default StyledAutocomplete;
```

Upd: Второй вариант, но как по мне, корявый:

```
import {
  Autocomplete as MuiAutocomplete,
  TextField,
  AutocompleteProps
} from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

type Props<
  T extends undefined = undefined,
  Multiple extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
  DisableClearable extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
  FreeSolo extends boolean | undefined = undefined
> = {
  autoCompleteProps?: AutocompleteProps<
    T,
    Multiple,
    DisableClearable,
    FreeSolo
  >;
};

interface IStyledAutocompleteProps extends Props {
  options: {
    label: string;
    year: number;
  }[];
}

const Autocomplete = styled(MuiAutocomplete)(({ theme }) => ({}));

const StyledAutocomplete: React.FC<IStyledAutocompleteProps> = ({
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...props}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField variant="outlined" {...params} />}
    />
  );
};

export default StyledAutocomplete;
```

Comment: На текущий момент у меня такой же вариант как у вас, но я хочу расширить интерфейс Autocomplete. Может я не понимаю чего-то, тогда объясните пожалуйста. Суть задачи: где-то в приложении добавить компонент <StyledAutocomplete options={top100Films} error={true}/> и чтобы не надо было постоянно расширять интерфейс IStyledAutocompleteProps т.к. пропсов может быть много

Comment: @qweezz проблема в том, что интерфейс, который вы импортируете, просит явной передачи undefined для обязательных параметров, которые вы передавать явно не хотите. Сделал примерно то, что вам надо, но как по мне получилась дичь + я ночью уже не сильно соображаю + на тайпскрипте уже год не работал. На вашем месте я бы забил и просто выводил типы по необходимости.